# How is the following chisel statement decoded?

Tags: scala, cpu, chisel

I am learning SonicBoom. The following sentence should be based on the decoding table to assign the corresponding decoding signal.

```
class CtrlSigs extends Bundle
{
  val legal           = Bool()
  val fp_val          = Bool()
  val fp_single       = Bool()
  val uopc            = UInt(UOPC_SZ.W)
  val iq_type         = UInt(IQT_SZ.W)
  val fu_code         = UInt(FUC_SZ.W)
  val dst_type        = UInt(2.W)
  val rs1_type        = UInt(2.W)
  val rs2_type        = UInt(2.W)
  val frs3_en         = Bool()
  val imm_sel         = UInt(IS_X.getWidth.W)
  val uses_ldq        = Bool()
  val uses_stq        = Bool()
  val is_amo          = Bool()
  val is_fence        = Bool()
  val is_fencei       = Bool()
  val mem_cmd         = UInt(freechips.rocketchip.rocket.M_SZ.W)
  val wakeup_delay    = UInt(2.W)
  val bypassable      = Bool()
  val is_br           = Bool()
  val is_sys_pc2epc   = Bool()
  val inst_unique     = Bool()
  val flush_on_commit = Bool()
  val csr_cmd         = UInt(freechips.rocketchip.rocket.CSR.SZ.W)
  val rocc            = Bool()

  def decode(inst: UInt, table: Iterable[(BitPat, List[BitPat])]) = {
    val decoder = freechips.rocketchip.rocket.DecodeLogic(inst, XDecode.decode_default, table)
    val sigs =
      Seq(legal, fp_val, fp_single, uopc, iq_type, fu_code, dst_type, rs1_type,
          rs2_type, frs3_en, imm_sel, uses_ldq, uses_stq, is_amo,
          is_fence, is_fencei, mem_cmd, wakeup_delay, bypassable,
          is_br, is_sys_pc2epc, inst_unique, flush_on_commit, csr_cmd)
      sigs zip decoder map {case(s,d) => s := d}
      rocc := false.B
      this
  }
}
```

But I want to know how this step is achieved.  `sigs zip decoder map {case(s,d) => s := d}`What does this code mean?

Zip and map seem to be functions within Vec.  I tried to check its official manual.

https://www.chisel-lang.org/api/latest/chisel3/index.html?search=zip  This manual is the most difficult manual I have ever seen.

He only gave the following explanation:

```
defzip[A1 >: T, B, That](that: GenIterable[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[IndexedSeq[T], (A1, B), That]): That
Definition Classes
IterableLike → GenIterableLike

defmap[B, That](f: (T) ⇒ B)(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[IndexedSeq[T], B, That]): That
Definition Classes
TraversableLike → GenTraversableLike → FilterMonadic
```

I can't understand what the manual is saying at all? I checked Chisel's books again. There is still no introduction to these two functions. Can someone please introduce? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zip` is a [standard Scala method](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/scala_collections/scala_collections_zip.htm). It join two sequences together in a sequence of 2-Tuples (Couple of values). Think about jacket zipper.

`map` is also a [standard scala method](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scala-map-method/). It apply a function to each membre of the sequence.

The function given to map here is `case(s,d) => s := d` this function use pattern matching to get the two tuple members `s` and `d`.
The value returned by this function is an assignation (connection) of `d` to `s`: `s := d`.

For better understanding of Chisel, I think that we must know a bit of Scala before.

Answer (score 1):

I have not attempted to compile it, and to be honest, I have only a vary vague understanding of what Chisel does at all, so this is just an educated guess:

- `sigs` is the sequence `Seq(legal, fp_val, ..., csr_cmd)` defined in the line above
- `decoder` is also a sequence of some entities that can appear on the right hand side of `:=`.
- `zip` pairs `sigs` and `decoder`-sequences elementwise, i.e. `[s1, s2, s3, ..., sN]` and `[d1, d2, d3, ..., dN]` are zipped into a sequence of pairs `[(s1, d1), (s2, d2), ..., (sN, dN)]`.
- `map` goes through the sequence, and does something to each pair. Since the result is unused, I assume that it actually should have been a `foreach`.
- `case` deconstructs the pairs into first and second components `s` and `d`
- `s := d` somehow wires together `s` and `d` (if you are working with Chisel, you probably know better than me what the `:=` means)

It could have been rewritten with a `for-yield`:

```
for ((s, d) <- sigs.zip(decoder))
yield s := d
```

but since the result is unused, it probably could have been written as

```
sigs.zip(decoder).foreach { case (s, d) => s := d }
```

or with the corresponding `for`-syntax:

```
for ((s, d) <- sigs.zip(decoder)) {
  s := d
}
```

---

Regarding the manual entry: that's a signature which is quite typical for Scala collection libraries. The pile of generic parameters is a type-level specification that ensures that the type of the returned collection is "as precise as possible". This has the advantage that one can write generic methods for a whole bunch of collections, without having to return one-size-fits-all-`List`s everywhere. Unfortunately, this also makes the signatures undecipherable to the novices.

This is the signature:

```
def zip[A1 >: T, B, That](that: GenIterable[B])(implicit bf: CanBuildFrom[IndexedSeq[T], (A1, B), That]): That
```

Here is how you read those signatures:

- Identify all the type variables that occur only in the `implicit` parameters. In this case, those would be `A1` and `That`.
- Identify all the type variables that occur in the return type. In this case, it's the `That`.

Now:

- If a type variable occurs only in the type of the `implicit` parameters, but not in the return type, then simply *ignore* them: this is just a way to specify the search space for the most appropriate implicit argument. You can ignore them, unless you are a library author who is attempting to plug-in your collections into the standard collection library. Consider it to be irrelevant library-author-to-library-author chatter.
- If some type variable `X` occurs both in the type of the `implicit` parameters and in the return type, then you can assume that it's "the best possible `X` you can think of".

Applied to this signature:

- `T` is the element type of your original vector
- `B` is the element type of the first argument (the collection you are zipping with)
- `A1` occurs only in the type of the implicit parameter: ignore it.
- `That` occurs in implicit parameter and in return type: assume it's "the best possible collection type".

All together, it gives you:

- You are starting with a vector with elements of type `T`
- You are zipping it with a sequence of elements of type `B`
- You can assume that `That` will be a collection of the most precise type, something like `Vec[(T, B)]` or at least `IndexedSeq[(T, B)]`. What it is, doesn't really matter, because you are invoking `foreach` on it anyway.

More generally, the idea would be that you can simply rely on the type inference, and assume that it will figure out the most appropriate result types everywhere.